# How to monitor ContentManager for my Mobile(3G) connection status Android?

Tags: android, mobile, wifi

If I use:

```
 allNetworksInfo = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
```

It will display

```
type :MOBILE subtype :UNKNOWN state :UNKNOWN isAvailable :false
type :WIFI subtype : state :DISCONNECTED isAvailable :true
type :MOBILE subtype :3G state :CONNECTED isAvailable :true
```

But if I use:

```
mobileNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
```

It will always display my mobile state

```
   type :MOBILE subtype :UNKNOWN state :UNKNOWN isAvailable :false
```

1. I am using 3G connection for BT.How to get the status of my Mobile by using ContentManager.If i use TYPE_MOBILE it displays ordinary mobile connection info.But i need 3G connection info.How to display my 3G connection status?
2. If I use statements in Global , I am not getting updated status from the ContentManager.If I need current status of MOBILE or WIFI ,need to write getNetwork method repeatedly?Currently iam using repeated statements whenver I require status? How can I used ContentManager for updated status of WIFI and MOBILE(3G)?
3. WifiManager.connect()/reconnect() takes time to connecting to the wifi. I used enableNetwork(netId) method for enable the selected WiFi accesspoint. Still it will take time. But my requirements is connect the wifi network immediately. If I am observing the WiFi Settins it dispayes Obtaining Addresss and after few seconds connected status. It takes time for obtaining the IP. How to remedy this one or get connect wifi immediately?